# With VoiceResponce - response.gather() with POST does not send Digits

Tags: twilio

I have a Twilio number configured to http://66.175.221.103:6543/ivr/860d247f4bc7 with GET.

The below code catches it in the GET and creates a voice response with the welcome message. The action is the same URL but with POST.

```
    itemID = request.matchdict['itemid']
    itemData = getItemData(request,itemID)
    if itemData is not None:
        itemResponses = getItemResponses(request,itemID)
        if request.method == 'GET':
            #Gather the response and POST to the same ID
            response = VoiceResponse()
            with response.gather(numDigits=1, action=request.route_url('ivr',itemid=itemID), method="POST") as g:
                 g.say(itemData["item_desc"],voice="alice", language="en-GB", loop=3)
            return twiml(response)                
        else:
            log.debug("*************888")
            log.debug(request.POST)
            log.debug("*************888")
            soption = request.POST.get('Digits', '0')
            noption = int(soption)
            for resp in itemResponses:
                if resp["resp_num"] == noption:
                    response = VoiceResponse()
                    response.redirect(request.route_url('ivr',itemid=resp["target_item"]))
                    return twiml(response)
            resp = VoiceResponse()
            resp.say("Error, was not able to find a response")
            resp.hangup()
            return twiml(resp)
```

That produces the following XML

```
<Response><Gather action="http://66.175.221.103:6543/ivr/860d247f4bc7" method="POST" numDigits="1"><Say language="en-GB" loop="3" voice="alice">Welcome to the Agricultural Podcast service. To listen to a podcast press 1. To request for new content press 2</Say></Gather></Response>
```

I press 1 for example and I get this on the post:

```
[('Called', '+17656133098'), ('ToState', 'IN'), ('CallerCountry', 'LS'), ('Direction', 'inbound'), ('CallerState', ''), ('ToZip', '46952'), ('CallSid', 'CAa127058ffcc4b148e8757ffb9025440c'), ('To', '+17656133098'), ('CallerZip', ''), ('ToCountry', 'US'), ('ApiVersion', '2010-04-01'), ('CalledZip', '46952'), ('CalledCity', 'MARION'), ('CallStatus', 'in-progress'), ('From', '+266696687'), ('AccountSid', 'ACaa8c3038f45a521b83c74789d51af27d'), ('CalledCountry', 'US'), ('CallerCity', ''), ('Caller', '+266696687'), ('FromCountry', 'LS'), ('ToCity', 'MARION'), ('FromCity', ''), ('CalledState', 'IN'), ('FromZip', ''), ('FromState', '')]
```

The Gather does a POST TO "http://66.175.221.103:6543/ivr/860d247f4bc7" but does not send "Digits" as part of the post.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason that is not documented in Twilio a get request to an URL cannot perform a post (using Gather) to the same URL. I separated the post and get in separated URLs and now all works fine.

Comment: That is strange behaviour and I'm going to look into why that is.